# Customize the proc freq output

Tags: sas

suppose to have the following table:

> ```
>        Patient          weight_class       Region       Social_Class        Year
>           1                 1                 A             0               2015
>           2                 2                 A             1               2015
>           3                 1                 A             0               2015
>           4                 4                 B             0               2015
>           5                 4                 C             2               2015
>           6                 3                 C             2               2015
>           7                 1                 C             2               2015
> ```

Is there a way to do the proc freq so that the output looks like this?

[image]

Finally, is there a way to write a macro/code in an "universal" way so that the format will be generated independently form the name of a specific variable? (To note: this is not fundamental with respect to the first question).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For just data set output you can follow `Proc FREQ` with `Proc TRANSPOSE`.

```
proc sort data=have;
  by year region social_class weight_class;
proc freq noprint data=have;
  by year region social_class;
  table weight_class / out=freqs;
proc transpose data=freqs out=want(drop=_name_ _label_) prefix=weight_class_;
  by year region social_class;
  id weight_class;
  var count;
run;
```

The output has dependencies on appearance ordering of values identifier (**id**) and does not have rows for some combinations year, region, social_class.

[image]

The ordering can be adjusted by adding more data that forces the transposed column ordering. Addtionally, a key_combinations data set will need to be created to force the groups that have no counts.

**Forcing data**

```
/* Predefined (includes year 2016 not in data) */

data years;   do year = 2015 to 2016; output; end; run;
data regions; do region = 'A', 'B', 'C'; output; end; run;
data socials; do social_class = 0 to 2; output; end; run;
data weights; do weight_class = 1 to 4; output; end; run;

proc sql;
  create table all_combinations as
  select year, region, social_class, weight_class 
  from years, regions, socials, weights
  ;
```

Or perhaps, just the independent coverage of the by variables

```
/* Assumed (contextual coverage) */

proc sql;
  create table all_combinations as
  select year, region, social_class, weight_class 
  from (select distinct year from have)
     , (select distinct region from have)
     , (select distinct social_class from have)
     , (select distinct weight_class from have)
  ;
```

Merge the forced data with the original data and setup a value for `Proc FREQ` `WEIGHT`.

```
data have_all;
  merge have(in=have) all_combinations ;
  by year region social_class weight_class ;
  freq=have;
run;

proc freq noprint data=have_all;
  by year region social_class;
  table weight_class / out=freqs_all;
  weight freq / zeros;
run;
proc transpose data=freqs_all out=want(drop=_name_ _label_) prefix=weight_class_;
  by year region social_class;
  id weight_class;
  var count;
run;
```

[image]

The wide (pivoted) style of data is often not overly useful for addtional analysis and it is better to leave the data in categorical form and instead generate a pivoted report using `Proc TABULATE`

**Plain tabulate** (does not cover all combinations, only those present in the data)

```
proc tabulate data=have;
  class region social_class year weight_class;
  table 
    year * region * social_class
  , weight_class * n
  ;
run;
```

[image]

**Tabulate with CLASSDATA=**

```
proc format;
  value na .='na';

proc tabulate data=have classdata=all_combinations;
  class year region social_class weight_class;
  table 
    year * region * social_class
  , weight_class * n=' '*f=na.
  ;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Richard for your help and for giving me many alternatives.

Comment: Hi Richard, supposing to consider the first piece of code (the solution you proposed) how can I include another variable? For example, suppose to have weight class and another variable "sex", is there a way to include this variable? The remaining will not change.

Comment: Yes, add `sex` to the `class` statement, and change the column-expression to `(weight_class sex) * n=' '*f=na.`